# Parameterizing fixtures not working on Pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have already used `params` on `fixtures` (`@pytest.fixture(params=params)`) to run the same test with several test cases. In this case, I think I'm doing exactly the same but this time the fixture doesn't return anything. What is strange is that the test runs as many times as many parameters I passed to the function.

So, my sample code:

```
def double(n):
    return 2 * n


TEST_CASES_DOUBLE = [
    #(input, expected)
    (1, 2),
    (2, 4),
    (3, 6),
]

# Fixtures


@pytest.fixture(params=TEST_CASES_DOUBLE)
def params_function_double(request):
    request.param


# Tests


def test_double(params_function_double):
    param, expected = params_function_double
    result = double(param)
    assert result == expected
```

And I get the errors:

```
======================================================================================= FAILURES ========================================================================================
_________________________________________________________________________ test_double[params_function_double0] __________________________________________________________________________

params_function_double = None

    def test_double(params_function_double):
>       param, expected = params_function_double
E       TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

test.py:56: TypeError
_________________________________________________________________________ test_double[params_function_double1] __________________________________________________________________________

params_function_double = None

    def test_double(params_function_double):
>       param, expected = params_function_double
E       TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

test.py:56: TypeError
_________________________________________________________________________ test_double[params_function_double2] __________________________________________________________________________

params_function_double = None

    def test_double(params_function_double):
>       param, expected = params_function_double
E       TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

test.py:56: TypeError
================================================================================ short test summary info ================================================================================
FAILED test.py::test_double[params_function_double0] - TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
FAILED test.py::test_double[params_function_double1] - TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
FAILED test.py::test_double[params_function_double2] - TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that your `params_function_double`  is not returning anything, hence why you get a NoneType error.

What you may be looking for is not the fixture decorator but rather the `pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator (see [this page](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html)). Here's how the test implementation would look like with it

```
def double(n):
    return 2 * n

# Tests
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "input_, expected",
    [(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6)]
)
def test_double(input_, expected):
    result = double(input_)
    assert result == expected
```